# Pagination without id column in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Is there any way of selecting only given columns without id column and using pagination (skip, take) in TypeORM. I'm doing this in NestJS:

**article.service.ts:**

```
async getAll(skip: number): Promise<Article[]> {
  return await this.articleRepository.find({
    select: {
      id: false,
      title: true,
      description: true,
      body: false,
      created_at: true,
      updated_at: false,
      author: {
        full_name: true
      }
    },
    relations: {
      author: true
    },
    skip: skip,
    take: 10,
    order: {
      created_at: 'DESC'
    }
  });
}
```

And in **article.controller.ts**:

```
@Get('articles')
async getAll(@Query('page') page: number) {
  if(!page) { page = 1; }
  const skip = (page - 1) * 10;

  const articles = await this.articlesService.getAll(skip);
  return {
    status: true,
    articles: articles,
    page: page,
  }
}
```

My **article.entity.ts**:

```
@Entity()
export class Article {
  
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  body: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.articles)
  author: User;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: string;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: string;
}
```

When I send a request to this endpoint error happens. I think this is because of pagination(skip, take).

```
QueryFailedError: column distinctAlias.Article_id does not exist
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (project/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (project/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:3601:25)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.getRawMany (project/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1573:29)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.executeEntitiesAndRawResults (project/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:3295:26)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.getRawAndEntities (project/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1617:29)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.getMany (project/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1707:25)
    at ArticlesService.getAll (project/src/articles/articles.service.ts:35:12)
    at ArticlesController.getAll (project/src/articles/articles.controller.ts:56:22)
    at project/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
```

But if I remove skip and take or select the id column it works. Is there any way that I can select other columns without id column and use pagination together

Comment: in your table does not exist column `column distinctAlias.Article_id does not exist`. check your sql query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved issue temporarily by selecting id columns and removing them before returning

```
articles.forEach(article => { delete article.id });
```

Here is the full function from **article.service.ts**:

```
async getAll(skip: number): Promise<Article[]> {
  const articles = await this.articleRepository.find({
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      description: true,
      body: false,
      created_at: true,
      updated_at: false,
      author: {
        full_name: true
      }
    },
    relations: {
      author: true
    },
    skip: skip,
    take: 10,
    order: {
      created_at: 'DESC'
    }
  });
  articles.forEach(article => { delete article.id });
  return articles;
}
```

**NOTE:** There should be a better solution though.

Comment: you can check the generated sql query. i am guessing that it needs ```id``` to establish relation between article and user. I am also looking for a way (in sequelize) to get result from relations without actually getting id in response, couldn't find any.